# SQL Server Consecutive Invoices excluding after 36 month gap

Tags: sql, sql-server

I’m struggling with a problem of using a formula to identify loyal customers and I’m hoping for some insight. 
The Loyal Customer criteria are as follows:

- The Customer must have been invoiced at least 4 times within 36
  months, with invoices falling in the following time ranges:

  - First Invoice (A) – This does not necessarily have to be the first time the
    customer is ever invoiced, just the first invoice that falls into
    this pattern
  - Second Invoice (B) – Has to occur from 1-12 months
    after Invoice A
  - Third Invoice (C) – Has to occur from 13-24 months
    after Invoice A
  - Fourth Invoice (D) – Has to occur from 25-36 months
    after Invoice A
- Once these criteria are met, all invoices with a    date greater than
  or equal to A are considered loyal customer    invoices

  - Only invoices with positive sub totals should be counted    as qualifying
    invoices (A, B, C, or D), but all invoices should be    counted once
    the customer meets the qualifying criteria

So far, I’m OK with this. Here is the query I’m using (It’s pretty slow, but I’m not running it very frequently so I’m not particularly concerned with speed):

```
;WITH 

T1 AS 
( 
SELECT
CUSTOMER_ID,
INVOICE_DATE,
DATEPART(YEAR, INVOICE_DATE)*12 + DATEPART(MONTH, INVOICE_DATE) AS YM
FROM INVOICE
WHERE Sub_Total > 0
),

T2 AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT 
A.CUSTOMER_ID,
A.INVOICE_DATE A_DATE
FROM T1 A
JOIN T1 B ON A.CUSTOMER_ID = B.CUSTOMER_ID AND (B.YM > A.YM AND B.YM <= (A.YM + 12))
JOIN T1 C ON A.CUSTOMER_ID = C.CUSTOMER_ID AND (C.YM > B.YM AND C.YM BETWEEN (A.YM + 13) AND (A.YM + 24))
JOIN T1 D ON A.CUSTOMER_ID = D.CUSTOMER_ID AND (D.YM > C.YM AND D.YM BETWEEN (A.YM + 25) AND (A.YM + 36))
)

SELECT DISTINCT 
I.CUSTOMER_ID,
C.CUSTOMER_NAME,
I.INVOICE_ID,
cast(i.Invoice_Date as Date) as Invoice_Date,
DATEPART(YEAR, I.INVOICE_DATE)*12 + DATEPART(MONTH, I.INVOICE_DATE) AS YM,
DATEPART(MONTH, I.INVOICE_DATE) AS Mo,
DATEPART(YEAR, I.INVOICE_DATE) AS Yr,
I.SUB_TOTAL
FROM INVOICE I
JOIN T2 ON T2.CUSTOMER_ID = I.CUSTOMER_ID AND I.INVOICE_DATE >= A_DATE
JOIN CUSTOMER C ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = I.CUSTOMER_ID
ORDER BY I.CUSTOMER_ID, INVOICE_DATE
```

However, what’s causing me to get stuck is another criteria stating that if a loyal customer goes 36 months without being invoiced they are no longer considered loyal, and any invoices following the 36-month gap should not be counted. If the customer completes the 4 qualifying invoices identified above (A, B, C, and D) again after the 36-month gap it is considered a new set of loyal invoices.

Example:

```
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| Invoice Month/Year | Qualifying Invoice | Count as Loyal? |
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
| 01/04              | N/A                | No              |
| 03/05              | A                  | Yes             |
| 09/05              | B                  | Yes             |
| 12/05              | N/A                | Yes             |
| 06/06              | C                  | Yes             |
| 04/07              | D                  | Yes             |
| 06/07              | N/A                | Yes             |
| 07/10              | N/A                | No              |
| 08/10              | N/A                | No              |
| 09/11              | A                  | Yes             |
| 10/11              | B                  | Yes             |
| 01/13              | C                  | Yes             |
| 04/14              | D                  | Yes             |
| 06/14              | N/A                | Yes             |
+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------+
```

I apologize if I’ve made this too complex. Ultimately, I’m hoping to gain some insight into how to exclude all invoices after a 36-month gap except those that meet the loyal customer criteria again.

Comment: As complex as this is, you might consider [making a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) so that it is easy to see the data.

Comment: Maybe another CTE that contains invoices that immediately follow a 36-month drought, and automatically set the loyal flag on those to No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to calculate the gaps, using a CTE. If you have SQL2012 or higher, the `lag` window function makes this simpler.

Good luck incorporating the information!

```
with x as (
  select
    invoice_id,
    customer_id,
    invoice_date,
    row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by invoice_date) rn
    -- SQL2012 has lag which is easier, can compute the gap directly (untested)
    -- datediff(month, lag(invoice_date, 1) over (
    --       partition by customer_id 
    --       order by invoice_date
    -- ), invoice_date) as gap
  from
    invoice
  where
    sub_total > 0
) select
  x1.*,
  datediff(month, x2.invoice_date, x1.invoice_date) gap
from
  x x1
    left join
  x x2
    on x1.customer_id = x2.customer_id and x1.rn = x2.rn + 1;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d95d5a/6)